# Install Windows Updates from a folder & return the status installed or not

Tags: windows, arrays, powershell

I wanted a help on verifying status of updates installed from a folder, here is the script below.

```
# Specify the location of the *.msu files
$updatedir = "C:\install\hvpatches"
foreach ($msu in $msus)
{
    write-host "Installing update $msu ..."
    $fullname = $msu.fullname
    # Need to wrap in quotes as folder path may contain spaces
    $fullname = "`"" + $fullname + "`""

###

$files = Get-ChildItem $updatedir -Recurse
$msus = $files | ? {$_.extension -eq ".msu"}
    # Specify the command line parameters for wusa.exe
    $parameters = $fullname + " /quiet /norestart"
    # Start wusa.exe and pass in the parameters
    $install = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "wusa",$parameters )
    $install.WaitForExit()
    write-host "Finished installing $msu"
}
```

The windows updates are installed from above script, what i wanted is some way to verify if these updates are installed correctly or give a status if the installation failed.

I hope some of our powershell gurus help me out :)

Thanks,
Vinith!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hardly a PS guru, but some time ago I was playing with checking updates in different context, so maybe my advice will be of use to you.

To the point. Try calling this snippet I have written down back then:

```
$session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session 
$searcher = $session.CreateUpdateSearcher() 
$result = $searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1 and Type='Software'" ) 
$result.Updates | get-member
```

After some time (it's kinda slow) you'll get list of things you can check. I don't know what information you have about these updates you're installing, but here's some possibly useful, like `Title` or `KBArticleIDs` number (hopefully containing some relevant info). Then you replace last line with what you want, e.g.

```
$result.Updates | select Title
```

and compare with data about recently installed updates.

*Sorry for somehow incomplete answer -- my current Windows box has some issues and above codes do not work exactly like I remember it. Don't hesitate to point out if it's simply wrong, errare humanum est! ;)*